# Excel VBA, Paste special adds trailing zeroes

Tags: vba, excel

I have raw data from ANSYS mechanical exported as `.xml` with the following format (2 rows, x number of columns):

```
Steps   Time [s]    [A] C1  (Total) [N] 
1       1             1,    4,4163e+005
```

I have a lot of files and I'm trying to combine these into one table in Excel using VBA. The script works fine with one exception, it does not interpret the scientific format correctly. My result is as follows:

> Steps 1
>   Time [s] 1
>   [A] C1  (Total) [N] 4,42E+09

Code looks as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer

Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents

'define table headers on row 1
wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1").Value = "Load Case"
wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B1").Value = "Load Case"
wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C1").Value = "Load Case"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'directory of source files
directory = "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Ansysxls\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

'Define the last used row in the target sheet
LastRow = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Do While fileName = "Asymmetric.xls"

 'define which workbook to open
  Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName)


   'loop through sheets in source file
    For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets

                  'Select range in source file
                  wb2.Sheets(sheet.Name).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select

                  'Replace commas with dot
                  Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

                  Selection.Copy

                 'Paste Special to target file <-----Smth wrong in my paste special???
                  wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & LastRow).PasteSpecial _
                  Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True
                  wb2.Sheets(sheet.Name).Activate

    Next sheet

    'define first row and last row of last import and add from what file the came
    FirstRow = LastRow
    LastRow = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'remove file ending ".xls" from column
    wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & FirstRow & ":" & "A" & LastRow).Value = Left(fileName, Len(fileName) - 4)

    Workbooks(fileName).Close
    fileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Create Table
 wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes, Header = xlYes).Name = "myTable1"

End Sub
```

Can anybody help me understand why it changes with from e+5 to e+9?

Comment: Can you give us an exact example of a value in the source cell (ie just cut and paste it here) together with the cell format of that cell.

Comment: If you'll notice, 44163e+005 [comma omitted intentionally]= 4.42E+09. The problem has something to do with the system not recognizing the decimal separator properly.

Comment: Ok, this should be an easy fix. Can you do me a favour and add the following line to your code just below the select range in source file line: `Debug.Print ".Text=" & wb2.Sheets(sheet.Name).Text & ", .Value=" & wb2.Sheets(sheet.Name).Value & ", .Value2=" & wb2.Sheets(sheet.Name).Value2` and post back here the result from your Immediate Window (usually at bottom of editor).

Comment: 441630 is the value in the cell format is scientific.

Answer (score 1):

Excel will 'interpret' the Total [N]) value (which has the comma in it) depending on the numbering system of your Excel application.

I believe if you paste a value of 4,4163e+005 into your worksheet, you will see a value of 4416300000, assuming your thousands are comma separated. In your case, however, you seem to want to convert the comma to a decimal point so that the true value is 441630. This can only be done if the value is a string, but yours probably isn't, it's most likely a number. I'm afraid I rather suspect your search and replace line makes no changes at all.

Although I can't see the values themselves, my bet would be that you need to divide each value by 10000 and then set the number format of your cells to "0.0000E+00".

I've put some code below that will loop through the values and make that change for you. You'll see that I've assumed each sheet only contains the 2 x 4 cell size, so adjust this if you need to.

Other comments about your code:

1. I think you need to put your last row update within the sheet loop. At a quick glance it looks as though you might be overwriting previous sheet data (ie the only data being written to your target is the source's last sheet data).
2. I'm not sure what you're intentions are with the `Dir()` function and then checking for a unique filename. It looks to me as if that will only loop once on a file called "Asymmetric.xls". If this is what you want then just define that workbook as an object. If you want to read all the workbooks in the directory then you need to run the `Dir()` loop `until filename = ""`. That's what I've assumed in my code.

   ```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim directory As String
   Dim fileName As String
   Dim source As Workbook
   Dim sht As Worksheet
   Dim targetRng As Range
   Dim rawValues As Variant
   Dim revisedValues() As Variant
   Dim rDimension As Long
   Dim cDimension As Integer
   Dim r As Long
   Dim c As Integer

       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False

       'define table headers on row 1
       With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
           .Cells.ClearContents
           .Cells(1, 1).Resize(, 3).Value = _
               Array("Filename", "Item", "Value")
           Set targetRng = .Cells(2, 2) 'ie "B2"
       End With

       'Directory of source files
       directory = "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Ansysxls\"
       fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

       Do Until fileName = ""

           'define which workbook to open
           Set source = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName)

          'loop through sheets in source file
           For Each sht In source.Worksheets

                'Select range in source file
                If Not IsEmpty(sht.Range("A1")) Then
                   rawValues = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value2

                   ' Manipulate the acquired data
                   rDimension = UBound(rawValues, 1)
                   cDimension = UBound(rawValues, 2)

                   ' Transpose the dimensions and manipulate the totalN value
                   ReDim revisedValues(1 To cDimension, 1 To rDimension)
                   For r = 1 To rDimension
                      For c = 1 To cDimension
                          If r = 2 And c = 4 Then ' it's totalN
                              ' Convert the data to a LongLong and divide by 10000
                              revisedValues(c, r) = CLngLng(rawValues(r, c)) / 10000
                          Else
                              revisedValues(c, r) = rawValues(r, c)
                          End If
                      Next
                   Next

                   'Populate the target sheet with revised values
                   Set targetRng = targetRng.Resize(cDimension, rDimension)
                   targetRng.Value2 = revisedValues

                   ' Define the scientific format
                   targetRng.Cells(4, 2).NumberFormat = "0.0000E+00"

                   ' Add the filename to column "A"
                   targetRng.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 1).Value2 = _
                       Left(fileName, (InStrRev(fileName, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))

                   ' Move the targetRng to the bottom of this range
                   Set targetRng = targetRng.Offset(targetRng.Rows.Count)
               End If
           Next

           source.Close
           fileName = Dir()

       Loop

       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True


   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Ambie, Thank you for your answer. It partly helps me, the solution dividing everything with 10000 since i have many different numbers for example:  1 1 1, 4,4163e+005 2,0973e+005 9250,5 82866 15051 1,1591e+005 5619,2 2,9187e+005 616,8  The manual solution i figured out yesterday was to open the .xls in note pad and serach and replace the commas with dots. Then my script worked fine.

Comment: Regarding point 2 in your comment, i just set it to a unique file since i wanted to work with one sheet at the time, it should be: 
    Do Until fileName <> ""

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Those number formats are a pain in Excel if you import data that uses different number systems.